# how to repartition rdd based on data size

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, rdd

I am working on spark streaming project which takes the data from Kafka applied some rules and save data in Hive. My problem is ingestion rate of data is not fixed. 60seconds may be 1 million message come or may be 1. I want to add repartition on Dstream. Because there is only 3 partition of Dstream, unable to process millions record within minute. repartition gives problem at the time of less than 20 records. It creates multiple small files in Hive.

```
dataStream.map(_._2).repartition(20)
```

My question is how I can rdd repartition based on rdd size. So that it can handle a single message or 1 million message.

Comment: Maybe you should reconsider your global pipeline instead -- e.g. have Spark dump its files into a Hive partition acting as "landing zone", then periodically merge-and-move the data into another partition (rename LANDING partition to TEMP, recreate LANDING, _INSERT...SELECT_ from TEMP to destination, drop TEMP -- and make sure nothing SELECTs that table while you are running the reorg).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do it in any useful way. Even if you decide to use `transform`

```
 stream.transform { rdd => {
   val n = rdd.count
   rdd.repartition(getNumParttitions(n))
 }}
```

this beats a whole purpose of the operation, as you have to scan all data before repartitioning and initial distribution will remain the bottleneck.

Instead, I'd recommend proper configuration, based either on `spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition` (old API) or configure backpressure (`spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled`, `spark.streaming.backpressure.initialRate`, newer API)

Comment: Dstream contains file which have many records. I have used spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition=1 properties but some time spark unable to process 900 files. batch size is 300 sec and kafka have 3 partitions. So I want to repartitions the rdd